# How to truncate non printable characters when piping from ZSH to VIM?

Tags: vim, pipe, zsh

From *Bash* all is clear:

```
$ ls /dev/loop* | vim -
/dev/loop0
/dev/loop1
/dev/loop2
/dev/loop3
/dev/loop4
/dev/loop5
/dev/loop6
/dev/loop7
/dev/loop-control
```

But from *ZSH* added some extra characters:

```
$ ls /dev/loop* | vim -
[0m[40;33;01m/dev/loop0[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop1[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop2[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop3[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop4[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop5[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop6[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop7[0m
[40;33;01m/dev/loop-control[0m
```

How to configure ZSH for better piping to VIM?

Comment: use `find` instead of `ls`. `ls` is for termital.

Comment: Thank you, but I need some option for my .zshrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have something like

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
```

in your zsh configuration.

You can confirm it with `type ls` command.

So what you can do is to overwrite it with:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

in your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Another reason not to try to use the output of `ls` programmatically.